# Creating a fake internal network for virtual machines

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a production application that consists of

```
 An app server VM1    - 192.168.0.4
 A database server DB - 192.168.0.5
```

VM1 connects to the DB using its IP address.

I want to mimic production VM1 on my development machine.  So it should connect to the db using the same IP as on production, but reach my development machine DB instance.

Ideally, I would not have to hardcode my development machine IP to make this work.  Any ideas?

Comment: I actually like the question (I've wondered things like this myself) but it'll probably get a better answer on either superuser.com or serverfault.com, probably the latter.

Comment: A quick Google found [rinetd](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/rinetd-redirects-tcp-connections-from-one-ip-address-and-port-to-another.html), if there's not a better way...

Comment: Why not use hostnames instead of IP addresses? Then you can use your hosts file or DNS to mimic whatever you want.

Comment: I like the rinetd option, thanks @minitech.  Is there a way to move the question to serverfault.com Christopher?  Should I just repost?

Comment: @juwiley: If it works for you, I've posted it as an answer now. If you want to get it moved, don't repost, flag it for moving. But I think it's probably okay here (nobody's voted to close it yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [rinetd](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/rinetd-redirects-tcp-connections-from-one-ip-address-and-port-to-another.html), you can set up a redirect from the production IP address to your own.

Answer (score 2):

1) It's a bad idea to mimic production IP addresses on test machines 
2) In answer to your question, just use a configuration file to describe the IP address of the system to connect to

Comment: Not sure why its a bad idea if its using private network addresses?  I'm hopeful that one day I can deploy the entire VM, instead of redeploying the app so it would be useful if my development network mirrored production.

Comment: Because one day you'll think you're debugging on your system and instead find that everything that you've done was on the client (LIVE/PRODUCTION) platform.  Good habits (and bad) tend to stick with you forever.